# Difference between wire and logic for this particular problem

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

I've worked this problem before in Verilog and no problem at all. Tried the same problem with SV and the problems started. The idea is to just show numbers on the first 3 7-segments based on switches. At first, it just didn't work (the 7 segments were "off"). The code I used there was:

```
module top(SW, CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, AN);

input [3:0] SW;
output CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG;
output [7:0] AN;

logic [6:0] seg = {CG, CF, CE, CD, CC, CB, CA};

assign AN = 8'b00011111;

bcd_decoder_0 dec1(.out(seg), .in(SW));

endmodule
```

You may ignore the instantiation to bcd_decoder_0, because it has proven to be right. As I said, the above code didn't work. Changing the data type of seg to "wire" solved everything:

```
module top(SW, CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, AN);

input [3:0] SW;
output CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG;
output [7:0] AN;

wire [6:0] seg = {CG, CF, CE, CD, CC, CB, CA};

assign AN = 8'b00011111;

bcd_decoder_0 dec1(.out(seg), .in(SW));

endmodule
```

Why that happened?

Note: I'm using NEXYS4DDR board from Xilinx, CA...CG represent the segments and AN represents which 7-seg is selected.

Comment: In `bcd_decoder_0`, is `out` an output? (I hope so!). If so, you are trying to drive `seg` with multiple drivers (from `dec1` and the declaration). This is not allowed for `logic` types, but is for `wire` types.

Comment: It is! It's the output from the BCD decoder (7 bits representing each segment of the 7-segment). Could you explain what do you mean by "drivers"?

Comment: By driver, I mean something trying to assign a value to a particular variable. When you have `logic [6:0] seg = {...}`, you are assigning ("driving") each bit in `seg` with `Cx`. Then `dec1` is trying to assign (drive) a new value on to each bit in `seg`, so it is not clear what the value of `seg` should be, hence the error.

Comment: While @dave_59 answered the actual question, this spiked my interest because it appears that this code relies on "reverse" driving through the net declaration assignment. I have never seen this done before, so I tried running a simulation of the code, which fails as expected. If it is true that this synthesizes and works in hardware, I am quite surprised.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the meaning of the RHS of the `=` in the signal declaration.

```
wire out = RHS;
```

is equivalent to

```
wire out;
assign out = RHS; // continuous assignment
```

And

```
logic out = RHS;
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
logic out;
initial out = RHS; // procedural assignment before time 0
```

This assignment happens before executing any other `initial` or `always` block.

Answer (score 0):

In SystemVerilog, the distinction between `logic` and `wire` revolves around their roles in procedural and continuous assignments. When you initially declared `logic [6:0] seg`, you used the `logic` type, which is commonly employed within procedural blocks. However, the subsequent `assign` statement for `AN` operates in a declarative style, outside any procedural block.

Switching the data type of `seg` to `wire` explicitly designates it as a net type suitable for continuous assignments. The `wire` type is conventionally used in connecting signals between modules and in continuous assignments. By making this adjustment, your code aligns more coherently with the typical usage of net types in SystemVerilog for continuous assignments, potentially resolving the issues you encountered. It underscores the importance of selecting the appropriate data type based on the specific context of its application within your code.